# Convert to uppercase all letters in a specific field

Tags: contacts

Is it possible to convert every letters in a specific field to uppercase?

I would like to have the addresses of my contacts on Civi written in uppercase (for postal service purposes).

The ideal scenario would be to force that field to be uppercase. But also converting it after the record is created would be sufficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible out of the box, but it would be an easy extension to write.  You could use [`hook_civicrm_pre`](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pre/), look for edit/create operations on Addresses and change the relevant fields to uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to USPS Web Tools which will do this standardization. Go to administer > localization > address settings. Signup https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm and you can get it working right away. That will take care of when create / update happen.

For existing records you can use [Cividesk Normalize](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividesk-normalize) and it allows you to perform normalization based on a contact ID range: https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividesk-normalize.

Comment: Hello Andy. Thank you for your answer. You give me hope! Jokes apart: I'm trying to enable USPS Web Tools. I've registered and entered the ID they gave me and the URL (both http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll and https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll). But nothing happens. If I create a new contact with a bad formatted address...nothing happens and the bad address saves. What am I missing? I've tried both production URLs

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS. 
  **text-transform: uppercase;**

Comment: That would work when viewing the contact summary page but it sounds like Marco needs it stored in the database as uppercase or at least stored in postal-friendly format.